# Can not create dump file with following command in java

Tags: java, sqlite, runtime, sh

Hello can anyone have face same problem in Sqlite3 while dumping file? When I running following code it running succesfully and generate dump file at specific position.

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/testsql.sqlite .dump > /home/ubuntu/newfinal.sql"});
```

But when We generate dump file where the space in between folder name.. it does not working or generate dump file? 
like my attempts are..

```
Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/testsql.sqlite .dump > /home/ubuntu/ubuntu one/newfinal.sql"});
```

so i encode url for spaces..like

```
String exportbackUpPath = "/home/ubuntu/ubuntu one/";
exportbackUpPath=exportbackUpPath.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/testsql.sqlite .dump > "+exportbackUpPath+"newgeneratedsql.sql"});
```

hence it replace with %20 still can't generate sqldump file. use also this for space

```
exportbackUpPath= URLEncoder.encode(exportbackUpPath, "UTF-8");
```

Still can not get success.. so can anybody help me to solve my issue?

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: i think its bug of sqlite3? but good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third String is interpreted by `/bin/sh` as the command to be executed. Normal Unix/Linux rules for command parsing apply. The original string is seen as

```
sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/testsql.sqlite .dump > /home/ubuntu/ubuntu one/newfinal.sql
```

by the shell, which means that sqlite3 is started with parameters

```
/home/ubuntu/testsql.sqlite .dump one/newfinal.sql
```

and the output is redirected to `/home/ubuntu/ubuntu`. Clearly, this is not what we want.

The easiest solution is to quote the file name so that the shell does not break it up into two words at the space:

```
Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/testsql.sqlite .dump > \"/home/ubuntu/ubuntu one/newfinal.sql\""});
```

Comment: +1.. sorry I have only one upvote for you :( Really awesome man.. can you elaborate this answer?

Comment: kindly explain this rule.. i am amazed that it is really worked..!!